# Devise's after_sign_in_path_for works after signing in normally, but does not work after signing in through Facebook or Twitter. Why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, devise, omniauth

I am working on a rails app right now that allows user's to log in normally, via twitter, and via Facebook as well. I am using devise, omniauth-twitter, and omniauth-facebook.

After signing up/registering, I want to redirect users to the page `verify_user_email_path`. I have my custom devise RegistrationsController which overrides the standard devise RegistrationsController. It looks like this:

```
class CustomDeviseControllers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def verify_email
    flash[:notice] = ""
  end

  def update_email
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    params[:user].delete(:current_password)
    if @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to bookshelf_index_url
    else
      @error_message = "You have entered an invalid email address"
      render "verify_email"
    end
  end

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      # I WANT TO REDIRECT USERS HERE AFTER SIGNING UP
      verify_user_email_path
    end
end
```

As you can see, after any user signs up, they should be redirected to `verify_user_email_path`. However/sadly, users are only redirected if they sign up normally. So when users register on my site (they enter in an email, a password, and then confirm their password), `after_sign_up_path_for` correctly redirects users to `verify_user_email_path`. If users sign up via Facebook/Twitter, the users are simply redirected to the root_url instead. That is the bug I need to fix.

This is my custom OmniauthCallbacksController (underneath the all caps comment is where I sign users in):

```
class CustomDeviseControllers::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user.persisted?
          # HERE IS WHERE I SIGN USERS IN
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

  [:twitter, :facebook].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end
end
```

Aaaand here, is my config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
    omniauth_callbacks: 'custom_devise_controllers/omniauth_callbacks',
    registrations: 'custom_devise_controllers/registrations' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get "users/verify_email" => 'custom_devise_controllers/registrations#verify_email', :as => :verify_user_email
    post "users/update_email" => 'custom_devise_controllers/registrations#update_email', :as => :update_user_email
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OmniauthCallbacksController doesn't use the method `after_sign_up_path_for` so obviously you don't get the redirection you want.

Also, that `class_eval` thing is completely unnecessary. Here's how that controller should look:

```
class CustomDeviseControllers::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    omniauth = env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.from_omniauth(omniauth)
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: omniauth.provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
      redirect_to verify_user_email_path
    else
      session["devise.#{omniauth.provider}_data"] = omniauth
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  alias_method :facebook, :all
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that class_eval advice. You are right, the old way was clunky and lame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using after_sign_up_path_for in my Registrations controller, I use after_sign_in_path_for in the application controller. If the number of sign in attempts equals one, that means the user just signed up.

Here is my application_controller.rb:

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.sign_in_count == 1
      verify_user_email_path
    else
      root_url
    end
  end
end
```

So now, whenever someone first signs up, they go to verify_user_email_path. If they are logging in any other time, they go to the root_url.

Thanks, everyone!